# Replacement parts for Macbook Air (13-inch, Early 2008) - broken hinge problem?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, screen, repair

I have a "MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2008)" with a broken hinge problem.

I'm presently outside the US and wont be able to go into a Genius Bar anytime soon. Besides, the laptop is far outside the warranty period so it is unlikely that any servicing could be done by Apple.

I'm planning to fix it on my own, but need to understand which replacement parts I need to order. Does anyone have any insights into what I should order?

Pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I had also posted about it a year back at:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/22873267#22873267

**Edit1**

```
Model   Model Identifier    Model Number    Configuration
MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2008)   MacBookAir1,1   MB003xx/A   MBAIR 13.3/1.6/2/80HDD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe replacing the Upper Case will solve your problem. [This guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+Models+A1237+and+A1304+Upper+Case+Replacement/856) from iFixIt will certainly help you do that.

If you would just want to replace the hinge itself, maybe Step 37 in the guide would be useful?

Check the top of the guide for required parts and tools!

Comment: Thanks Felix for the link! I had seen a different guide, but this one is more useful... do you have any thoughts on what exactly would be broken by looking at the pictures? The hinge is 'affected'... but is that what is actually broken?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure as I'm not a repair tech or anything. It looks like something is stuck though. Maybe use the guide to disassemble your Air and check all parts are in tact? This may be a good approach before purchasing a new case

Comment: How do I determine my Air's model number - like A1237 and A1304 ? Looking up the serial number showed (see edit1)

Comment: Could you check please whether these are your specs?

http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/specs/macbook-air-core-2-duo-1.6-13-specs.html

If so, then you have model number A1237

Comment: Great - yes, its exactly that. This site https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do
showed: ~VIN,MACBOOK AIR 13/1.6/2GB/80GB

Comment: If this solved your issue, could you please accept my answer as the solution to close this post?

Comment: Sure - still working on it though (waiting for the part to arrive and then attempting the repair!) :)